# Need to access Bicycle bluetooth speed sensor service name. Bluetooth assigned services page is down. Where else can I figure this information out?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to lookup the services I need to change this example from a battery_service into a bicycle speed sensor service. Simply doing `navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(acceptAllDevices=true)` works to pair to the bicycle speed sensor device, but it errors out because I didn't provide the right service name for it.

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ services: ['battery_service'] }] })
.then(device => { /* … */ })
.catch(error => { console.error(error); });
```

I figured out heart rate is `{filters:[{services:[ 'heart_rate' ]}]})` just from guessing. Still haven't figured out the bicycling speed and cadence sensor name. Is there a way to introspect `requestDevice` to get this since the documentation is down?

https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#biblio-bluetooth-assigned-services

Gives the link

https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/descriptors/Pages/DescriptorsHomePage.aspx

Which the page no longer is there, 403 Forbidden error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The specifications have been moved and can now be found in: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/gatt-specification-supplement-4/

Comment: Thank you for the doc. This isn't what I'm looking for (I don't think?) as it doesn't have a hit for `heart_rate` in it. Presumably the document I'm looking for has both `battery_service` and `heart_rate` in it, as well as whatever the cadence and speed sensor are called.

Answer (score 0):

All standardized Bluetooth GATT UUID strings handled by Chrome are in this file: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/bluetooth/bluetooth_uuid.cc. And I believe this line below is what you're looking for.

```
  {"cycling_speed_and_cadence", 0x1816},
```

This means you could either use the string name or its UUID:

```js
// This works.
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ services: ['cycling_speed_and_cadence'] }] });

// And this works as well ;)
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ services: [0x1816] }] });
```

https://web.dev/bluetooth is also a good place to start.